# $_FILES array empty from form submited in IE8

Tags: html, forms, iframe, internet-explorer-8, submit

I am trying to create an upload script and am having issues with IE8 and older. (of course ;) ) In all other browsers it works fine but in IE8 the $_FILES array is empty. This is the html code being used:

```
<FORM method=post action=api/upload.php target=form8230839>
    <INPUT name=file type=file>
    <INPUT value="Submit Query" type=submit>
    <INPUT name=id value=id66130748349062623150808191 type=hidden>
</FORM>
<IFRAME id=form8230839 name=form8230839></IFRAME>
```

(note the code is being generated by javascript createElement so IE8 is writing it out with the caps and lack of quotes around attributes.)

Then in the php file I am doing:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

which returns as just an empty array? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag.

Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be a possible duplicate of this one:

[$_FILES array in PHP is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627017/files-array-in-php-is-empty)

Nevertheless, as others have pointed out, and also from the attached, the solution is to add:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to your form.